# Move a single file by extension with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, move

this is my very first post on this site but as I already found much help on stackoverflow, I now ask this question myself. I did not find an answer to this issue. My English isn't that good and as my Problem is quite complex, I hope you guys are all able to understand me. If not or if there are any questions that are needed to be able to help me, feel free to ask.

So I want to make a Batch file that moves files by the Extension (in my case, it's .pdf) but not all of them. I know there is this command:

```
move "Y:\Scan\*.pdf" "Y:\Scan\Archive\"
```

But this will move all pdf files to the Archive Folder and I don't want that.
To get a better overview what my plan is, a small description is needed I guess.
Imagine you have a home Server and your Computer is connected to it, a Printer and a scanner aswell. I have many documents in Folders in my home Office and I want to have them all on my Server. This is done trough scanning all Sheets of paper in These Folders. Everytime I scan something, this is saved as .pdf in a Folder on my local Computer, sorted by time and Looks like this: 2017-06-15-10-30.pdf

My current script is asking 3 times for userinput. One time for a village Name, one time for a street's Name and one time for the number of the house because the Folders for the Archive should be named like the corresponding house they are referring to. So I have These 3 Inputs in my Batch already and also the whole Folder Name saved in a new variable.

My plan is to now ask the user how many pdf's are corresponding to the last created Folder and whatever the user is typing, this amount of files will be stored in that Folder. To understand this a Little better, here is what i've done so far (my Batch code).

```css
@echo off
cls

title Archive-Script (by Relentless)
color 0b


:reset
cls

REM This is the village's name
SET ON=""
REM This is the street's name
SET SN=""
REM This is the number of the house
SET HN=""
REM This is a variable to store whether the user wants to reset the variables or not (used later)
SET RESET=""


:start
cls
IF %RESET% == N echo To overwrite the village's name, please enter the name again and hit enter. If you don't want to overwrite the name, just hit enter!
IF NOT %RESET% == N echo Please enter the village's name (confirm by pressing enter):
IF %RESET% == N echo Current name: %ON%
set /p "ON="
echo The village's name was set to %ON%!

echo.

IF %RESET% == N echo To overwrite the street's name, please enter the name again and hit enter. If you don't want to overwrite the name, just hit enter!
IF NOT %RESET% == N echo Please enter the street's name (confirm by pressing enter):
IF %RESET% == N echo Current name: %SN%
set /p "SN="
echo The street's name was set to %SN%!

echo.

IF %RESET% == N echo To overwrite the house's number, please enter the number again and hit enter. If you don't want to overwrite the number, just hit enter!
IF NOT %RESET% == N echo Please enter the house's number (confirm by pressing enter):
IF %RESET% == N echo Current number: %HN%
set /p "HN="
echo The house's number was set to %HN%!

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.

SET FOLDERNAME="%ON%, %SN% %HN%"
echo The folder %FOLDERNAME% will now be created!
mkdir ""%FOLDERNAME%""
timeout /t 2 /nobreak


:pdfmove
cls
echo How many pdf-files are corresponding to the latest created folder?
set /p "PDF="
for /l %%x in (1,1,%PDF%) do (
 echo %%x
 move Y:\Scan\*.pdf Y:\Scan\%FOLDERNAME%\
)


:resetoption
cls
echo %ON%
echo %SN%
echo %HN%
echo.
echo Should the variables be resetted again? (J/N)
set /p "RESET="
IF %RESET% == J goto reset
IF %RESET% == N goto start
```

As you can see, I already tried to implement the move Option, but this will move ALL pdf files instead of one on each for Loop. Can anyone help me with that? I guess the code is pretty simple to understand.

Greetz Relentless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,%PDF%) do (
 set "moved="
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "y:\scan\*.pdf" '
  ) do if not defined moved (
    echo %%x : %%a
    set "moved=Y"
    move "Y:\Scan\%%a" Y:\Scan\%FOLDERNAME%\
    )
)
```

I believe what you want to do is to move a user-input number of pdfs.

The above change will, for each `%%x`, first set the flag `moved` to *nothing*, then perform a directory-scan, in `/b` basic form (filename only) `/a-d` with no directorynames. Each of the filenames present in the directory will be assigned to `%%a` in turn. The `delims=` option allows filenames that contain spaces to be processed.

When the first file is found, its name is `echo`ed with the sequence number and the flag is `set` to `Y` (any non-empty string will do). The file is then moved.

When the `for...%%a...` processes the next filename, `moved` is now set to a value, so no more file-moves are performed.

The entire process is then repeated for each value of `%%x`, so `%PDF%` moves of the first `.pdf` filename found in the source directory will be moved because one is moved each time and the `dir` command will not find the file that was last moved because well - it's been moved and hence is no longer in the source directory.

---

OK, here's a fix to produce a variable number of spaces

```
SET "tspaces=T"
:addspace
SET "tspaces=%tspaces% "
CALL SET "testspace=%%tspaces:~%pdf%%%"
IF "%testspace%" neq " " GOTO addspace

FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,%pdf%) DO (
 set "moved="
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "y:\scan\*.pdf" '
  ) do if not defined moved (
    echo %%x : %%a
    set "moved=Y"
    call move "Y:\Scan\%%a" "Y:\Scan\%FOLDERNAME%\olddocumen%%tspaces:~0,%%x%%.pdf"
    )
)
```

The first part sets up `tspaces` to `t`+a sufficient number of spaces.

Note that in the second part, the `move` is now `call`ed which resolves the variable-substring. Since `%%x` varies from 1 to `%pdf%` then the selection from `tspaces` is `%%x` characters - it has a minimum of 1, when the final character of `olddocument` is required; thereafter a number of spaces follow, so the `t` is the initial value of `tspaces`.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you for the fast reply!

Comment: Okay, I tried it and first I got the message that the path couldn't be found so I added quotations to the paths behind the move command and then I got a Syntax error but no additional Information where this Syntax error could be located. Any ideas?

Comment: First step is to figure out which command is yielding the message. I'd insert `REM ` before the `move` command to make that command a comment. If that cures the problem, the `move` is at fault, otherwise it's the `dir`. Make very sure that you've typed the lines exactly as I've shown them (cut-and-paste is best) - batch can be very sensitive to syntax at times. Most of all, be very careful about the quotes - single and double, and don't use a word-processor since WPs (and WP-wannabes like Notepad) try to "format" the text or change to "smart quotes" Use a real editor like editplus or Notepad++

Comment: Solved it, was missing a simple ":" behind one Y-drive.
Now there's only one Thing left, I want to have. After the files are moved, the script should also rename the files in the Folder that was just created. For example I moved 3 pdf files and now the script has to go into the Folder and Change the Name from "2017-06-15....whatever.pdf" to "OldDocument.pdf" and whenever another file is renamed, add a space behind the Name so the seccond pdf is like "OldDocument .pdf". Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible - with enough attention, almost anything is. The easy way however is to change the `move` statement to `move "Y:\Scan\%%a" Y:\Scan\%FOLDERNAME%\OldDocument%%x.pdf"` which will generate `olddocument1.pdf``,`olddocument2.pdf`,`olddocument3.pdf` and so on. Note alsoo that if you want to overwrite an existing file, you may need to add `/y` to the `move`

Comment: I get the Point but the importance is that the files are different from each other by another space from document to document so: olddocument.pdf, olddocument .pdf, olddocument  .pdf